# Datetimepicker restrict start and end date

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, twitter-bootstrap-3

So here i have two datetimepicker. Im using datetimepicker by the way. Start datetimepicker and End datetimepicker1. Let say i try to pull list of recard based on start and end datetime selected by user. We assume user will select start datetime for example 2019-07-08 08:00:00, Once the start datetime is selected the event will triggered where the End datetime they only able to select limit 2-3 days range based on the selected Start datetime. Example start datetime is 2019-07-08 08:00:00, then the End datetime user only able to select within 2019-07-09 08:00:00 to 2019-07-11 08:00:00.. User cannot select more than that range. Actually its based on the Start datetime.

here my current starting code

```
var minDate = moment().subtract(4, 'days');
var maxDate = moment();
$('#datetimepicker, #datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format:'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss',
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    showClear: false,
    useCurrent: false
});
```

Any idea how to have such function using Datetimepicker?

Comment: Which Datetimepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js i using this datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

Since the value for `#datetimepicker1` depends on the value of `#datetimepicker` you can try this:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format:'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss',
    showClear: false,
    useCurrent: false
}).on('changeDate', function(ev){
    var startDate = ev.date.valueOf();
    var endDate = startDate + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3); // add 3 days to the selected date
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker('setEndDate', endDate);
});
```